# Im using Cosmos DB and run the SQL command and get error Code:SC1001

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Below is the line that got the error

```
--

CREATE TABLE `data_calculation` (
  `calcu_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `calcu_date` date NOT NULL,
  `totalalumni` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totalmale` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totalfemale` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkd` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkg` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkl` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkb` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldcn` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totalemployed` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totalentrepreneur` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totalunemployed` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totalfurtherstudy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totalwaitingjob` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldktsalary4001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldktsalary3001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldktsalary2001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldktsalary1501` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldktsalary1001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldktsalary1000` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkdsalary4001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkdsalary3001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkdsalary2001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkdsalary1501` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkdsalary1001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkdsalary1000` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkgsalary4001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkgsalary3001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkgsalary2001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkgsalary1501` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkgsalary1001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkgsalary1000` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldklsalary4001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldklsalary3001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldklsalary2001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldklsalary1501` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldklsalary1001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldklsalary1000` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkbsalary4001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkbsalary3001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkbsalary2001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkbsalary1501` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkbsalary1001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldkbsalary1000` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldcnsalary4001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldcnsalary3001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldcnsalary2001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldcnsalary1501` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldcnsalary1001` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totaldcnsalary1000` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Gateway Failed to Retrieve Query Plan: Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":208,"end":211},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'SET'."}]}
ActivityId: d5f90a15-9fcc-44a5-8cdf-2fd34b811add, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're trying to execute T-SQL command against a Cosmos DB account.

You cannot run T-SQL commands against a Cosmos DB. Cosmos DB SQL API supports writing SQL commands but it is different than the SQL commands that you write for a SQL Server.

Please see this link to understand the SQL command support in Cosmos DB accounts targeting SQL API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-getting-started.